# Resolving a puzzle (optimal solution)

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star, heuristics

I have a puzzle 3x3 of numbers as follow:

```
3 | 5 | 2
7 | 8 | 9
1 | 6 | 4
```

Being the solution:

```
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```

The rule is that I can only move nearby "pieces" until I get the solution.

My take on this was to calculate the offset and then run it into a "fancy" algorithm for an efficient solution. However, I can only think of using bruteforce and checking the amount of steps the program did to find the most efficient one.

In offset I mean:

```
(2,  0) | (0,  1) | (-1,  0)
(0,  1) | (0,  1) | ( 0,  1)
(0, -2) | (1, -1) | (-2, -1)
```

Which are the offsets of x and y in a cartesian plan. I got the following which does calculate the offset, but no thoughts on the "fancy algorithm".

https://ideone.com/0RP83x

Is there a efficient way to get the least movements for the solution without using bruteforce ?

Comment: How do pieces move? Do you swap them?

Comment: Oops. Yes. But only on the X or Y axis. No diagonal move.

Comment: I might have an idea. I'll work on something and post a solution and see if you like it.

Comment: You need to devise a good heuristic which you can combine with A* or interactive deepening A*. Have a look into pattern database, linear conflict and manhattan distance heuristics.

Comment: My thought process was to use address swapping on the array to move values to the correct location and recalculate the relative positions based on their new positions. this would use a separate `int[][] values = int[3][3]{};` array to keep track of the actual cell values. I worked on it for an hour and it seems like it might work. Someone else with more time might be able to make it work.

Comment: @JoelTrauger: That’s not how you declare/create arrays in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to consider the grid as a node (part of a graph).

Let's write the grid

```
abc
def
ghi
```

as a single line `abcdefghi`.

You start with node `352789164` and you want to reach node `123456789`.

The neighbours of a node are all the nodes you can reach by applying swaps.
e.g `123456789` has for neighbours

```
[
  213456789, 132456789,
  123546789, 123465789,
  123456879, 123456798,
  423156789, 153426789,
  126453789, 123756489,
  123486759, 123459786
]
```

Then you can apply A*, by supplying:

- `d(nodeA, nodeB) = weight(nodeA, nodeB) = 1` (all swaps cost 1)
- `h(node)` = minimal number of swaps needed to get to solution.

To have the minimal `h`, consider counting the misplaced digits.

- If you have an even number of misplaced digits, you need at minimum "half of it" swaps
- If you have an odd number of misplaced digits, then half + 1 (e.g 312 for goal 123 needs 2 swaps)

Below example in js where I copy pasted code from [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416703/resolving-a-puzzle-optimal-solution)

```js
function h (node) {
  const s = ''+node
  let misplaced = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    if (parseInt(s[i]) != i+1) {
      misplaced++
    }
  }
  if (misplaced % 2 === 0) {
    return misplaced / 2
  }
  return Math.ceil(misplaced / 2)
}

function d (a, b) {
  return 1
}

const swaps = (_ => {
  const arr = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[5,6],[7,8],[8,9],[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[4,7],[5,8],[6,9]]
  function makePermFunc([a,b]) {
    a--
    b--
    return function (node) {
      const s = (''+node)
      const da = parseInt(s[a])
      const db = parseInt(s[b])
      const powa = 9 - a - 1
      const powb = 9 - b - 1
      node -= da * 10**powa
      node -= db * 10**powb
      node += da * 10**powb
      node += db * 10**powa
      return node
    }
  }
  const funcs = arr.map(makePermFunc)

  return node => funcs.map(f => f(node))
})();

//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm
function reconstruct_path (cameFrom, current) {
  const total_path = [current]
  while(cameFrom.has(current)) {
    current = cameFrom.get(current)
    total_path.unshift(current)
  }
  return total_path
}


// A* finds a path from start to goal.
// h is the heuristic function. h(n) estimates the cost to reach goal from node n.
function A_Star(start, goal, h) {
  // The set of discovered nodes that may need to be (re-)expanded.
  // Initially, only the start node is known.
  const openSet = new Set([start])

  // For node n, cameFrom[n] is the node immediately preceding it on the cheapest path from start to n currently known.
  const cameFrom = new Map()

  // For node n, gScore[n] is the cost of the cheapest path from start to n currently known.
  const gScore = new Map()
  gScore.set(start, 0)

  // For node n, fScore[n] := gScore[n] + h(n).
  const fScore = new Map()
  fScore.set(start, h(start))

  while (openSet.size) {
    //current := the node in openSet having the lowest fScore[] value
    let current
    let bestScore = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
    for (let node of openSet) {
      const score = fScore.get(node)
      if (score < bestScore) {
        bestScore = score
        current = node
      }
    }
    
    if (current == goal) {
      return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)
    }
    openSet.delete(current)
    swaps(current).forEach(neighbor => {
      // d(current,neighbor) is the weight of the edge from current to neighbor
      // tentative_gScore is the distance from start to the neighbor through current
      const tentative_gScore = gScore.get(current) + d(current, neighbor)
      if (!gScore.has(neighbor) || tentative_gScore < gScore.get(neighbor)) {
        // This path to neighbor is better than any previous one. Record it!
        cameFrom.set(neighbor, current)
        gScore.set(neighbor, tentative_gScore)
        fScore.set(neighbor, gScore.get(neighbor) + h(neighbor))
        if (!openSet.has(neighbor)){
          openSet.add(neighbor)
        }
      }
    })
  }
  // Open set is empty but goal was never reached
  return false
}

console.log(A_Star(352789164, 123456789, h).map(x=>(''+x).split(/(...)/).filter(x=>x).join('\n')).join('\n----\n'))
console.log('a more basic one: ', A_Star(123654987, 123456789, h))
```